# stopping a for loop for a specific time and adjust images in Glide

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-glide

I am generating volley request that fetches images from server and displayed in Glide. I use for loop that parse response and display images in Glide. I want to display image one and after 5/10 seconds i want to change it with index. Problem i am facing is that when for loop starts its display image that is on last index. 
mu code is:

```
StringRequest fetchingAddsForMainScreen= new StringRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            int counter=0;
            try {
                JSONObject object= new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray=object.getJSONArray("slots");
                for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String packageFullName=jsonObject.getString("adurl");
                    System.out.println("Package Full Name is:"+packageFullName);
                    String packageName = packageFullName.substring(packageFullName.indexOf("?")+3, packageFullName.length() );
                    System.out.println("Package Name is:"+packageName);
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(jsonObject.getString("imgurl")).into(iVAddOne);
counter++;
if (counter==1)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "one Time counter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //break;
                            }
                            else if (counter==2)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Two Time counter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "many Time counter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
```

How i can stop for loop for 10 seconds and paste image in glide for next index.

Answer (score 0):

Easy hack is to run the for loop in a parallel thread and call sleep(5000) at the end of every iteration.

More complex solution that is more elegant and fits better with android is to use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) so that you can can set a repeating task which would change the image every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help.

```
int CODE_PAUSE_TIME = 3000; //IN MILLISEC
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            //Write your code here before there is a pause
      try{
        Thread.sleep(CODE_PAUSE_TIME);
      }catch(Exception e){
         //write your code here after there is a pause.
      }

        }
```

I hope this helps you.